# for loop wont move on to next iteration gspread

Tags: python, python-2.7, gspread

This will print the first sheets results, but it wont loop past the first page.
The output is fine and accurate for the first page, it just wont loop past that and I don't know why. I'm new, so forgive me if this is obvious, but I've read up on documents and can't find the answer. Thank you.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


sheets_of_months= ['May 2018 Chem Readings', 'April 2018 Chem Readings', 'June 2018 Chem Readings']


scope= ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


creds= ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client= gspread.authorize(creds)


def get_customers():
    for name_of_sheet in sheets_of_months:
        spread_sheet= client.open(name_of_sheet)
        work_sheet= spread_sheet.sheet1
        result= work_sheet.row_count
        print result, name_of_sheet


get_customers()
```

I realized the issue is in this line

```
work_sheet= spread_sheet.sheet1
```

for whatever reason this stops it.

Edit:

```
def get_customers():
    for name_of_sheet in sheets_of_months:
        spread_sheet= client.open(name_of_sheet)
        print name_of_sheet
        work_sheet= spread_sheet.sheet1
        print name_of_sheet
```

The output for this is crazy.

```
May 2018 Chem Readings
April 2018 Chem Readings
June 2018 Chem Readings
June 2018 Chem Readings
```

It loops through once up to the first print, then hits the work_sheet= spread_sheet.sheet1 line, after that it starts over again and prints only once. Odd....

Comment: no you should not need continue. But this is funky.If you comment out (by putting # at the beginning) the spread_sheet= and work_sheet= lines and just set result = 1, you should find that all 3 times through the loop happen. subtle

Comment: @JeremyKahan I found the same thing, this is why I'm confused, it seems as if the line assigning work_sheet is somehow causing it to not be a loop anymore. It's odd...

Comment: what happens if after the line spread_sheet= and before work_sheet= you put assert (spread_sheet!=None), 'testing sheet opened'

Comment: @JeremyKahan nothing changes sadly.

Comment: so if there is no assertion error message, maybe the sheet really is open. But maybe not because an error was raised which stopped execution. What happens if put try: the line before spread_sheet= (which now gets indented) and after it put except gspread.SpreadsheetNotFound  as fnf_error: and then on the next line print fnf_error?

Comment: @JeremyKahan This made it loop completely! I'm not sure why though. But that made it work! Why exactly is that the case?

Comment: Might the worksheet not have a sheet 1? Try putting in for w in name_sheet.worksheets() print w.title, w.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174379/discussion-between-jeremy-kahan-and-wowwee).